# mysql syntax error on removing duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to remove rows having duplicate `hid` column values with this query:

```
DELETE FROM dmf_product_match_unmatches as pmu1
WHERE ID not in 
(
    SELECT MAX(ID) as maxRecId
        FROM dmf_product_match_unmatches as pmu2
        GROUP BY hid       
);
```

But this gives

```
QL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as pmu1
WHERE ID not in 
(
    SELECT MAX(ID) as maxRecId
        FROM dmf_prod' at line 1
```

The query looks fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the case when the error message does not match the error by some unknown reason. I don't understand why so - while executing in CLI the error message must be

> You can't specify target table 'pmu1' for update in FROM clause

The root of the error - you cannot use the table to be altered as datasource of the subquery in WHERE.

You must use multiple-table DELETE syntax instead:

```sql
DELETE pmu1
FROM dmf_product_match_unmatches as pmu1
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT MAX(ID) as ID, hid
            FROM dmf_product_match_unmatches as pmu2
            GROUP BY hid) pmu3 USING (ID, hid)
WHERE pmu3.ID IS NULL;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=202cddc698cda3f83e0172c7e4e28a7d

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation on DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) doesn't make this clear in the syntax reference at the top of the page, but if you define an alias for a table, you must use the syntax like this:

```
DELETE pmu1 FROM dmf_product_match_unmatches as pmu1
...
```

The reason is that using the `as` keyword  makes the parser think you're using the multi-table delete syntax, even though you are only referencing one table in your outer query. The syntax reference on the documentation I linked to shows that `DELETE tbl_name FROM ...` syntax is required if you make use of *table_references* syntax, which you are if you use the `as` keyword.

The documentation does have a note lower down:

> If you declare an alias for a table, you must use the alias when referring to the table:
>
> ```
> DELETE t1 FROM test AS t1, test2 WHERE ...
> ```

Alternatively, you don't need to define an alias in this query, so you can use the simpler syntax:

```
DELETE FROM dmf_product_match_unmatches
...
```

Comment: *but if you define an alias for a table, you must use the syntax like this* Incorrect. You **must** only when multiple-table syntax is used and the rows must be deleted from some, not from all, tables. If not (including single-table deletion) then you may but not must.

Comment: @Akina, Please test this: `DELETE FROM mytable AS myalias ...` You will get a syntax error. If you omit the alias, you get no syntax error. If you reference the alias like `DELETE myalias FROM mytable AS myalias ...` then you get no syntax error.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=afdadf49671d0d0d93d13e6c4c6a5e0e

Comment: Aha, if one changes your dbfiddle to MySQL 5.7, it exhibits the syntax error.